# Created a python package in TestPypi but I can't import it

Tags: python, python-3.x, packaging, pypi

I've deployed my first package in `test.pypi.org` as you can find it [here](https://test.pypi.org/project/pyupurs/0.0.1/)

I have installed my package in my virtual environment (`.venv`).

```
$ pip list
```

returns :

```
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        20.1
pyupurs    0.0.2
setuptools 46.0.0
wheel      0.34.2
```

But as you can see here, I cannot import it within my interpreter.

```
Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyupurs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyupurs'
```

Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: @phd edit done.

Comment: Thanks! I retracted my vote.

Comment: I cant install your distribution so this question cant help me. You have a problem with your dependencies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your package `pyupurs` there is nothing that can be imported under same name. The **distribution package** `pyupurs` installs top-level **importable package** named `stateless_file_ops`. So you can only do

```
import stateless_file_ops
```

If you want to change that you need to change you subdirectory structure perhaps adding a directory `pyupurs` with file `__init__.py` in it.